# Typescript does not enforce function parameters

Tags: typescript, function, parameters

The snippet below does NOT throw a type an error:

```
type Func = (args: { a: number, b: string }) => boolean
let fn: Func = () => true
```

Why is that? How can I enforce that every function of type Func must have all the parameters declared?

Comment: While this is a good question, I would for a moment reflect on the reason, why do you need this? Why are the arguments required if they don't affect the output?

Comment: @Nit That is my point; there should be a type error to guard against someone creating such a function, but there isn't

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of the above, let me know if you think the asnwer does not apply and I can reopen